# tablelist label color while mouse hovers

Tags: user-interface, tcl, tk-toolkit

I've configured the background color of some lables of my tablelist by using the `columnconfigure $ColumnIndex -labelbg`method.

However, the background color changes while the mouse hovers over the labels. I couldn't find any `-activebackground` method and I wish the background color will stay the same even when the mouse hovers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply explored all the children of the tablelist, found the correct label widget reference `.t.hdr.t.f.l0` and updated the `activebackground` property